# Doctrine2 Symfony2 Paginator fails with orderBy

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Using this code within a Repo

```
 $builder = $this->createQueryBuilder("s");

 $builder->addOrderBy("s.name", "ASC");

 $pagi = new Paginator($builder->getQuery(), true);

 $data = $pagi->getIterator()->getArrayCopy();
```

Results in this error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3065 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause
>   is not in SELECT list, references column 'dctrn_result.name_5' which
>   is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT") in
>   AppBundle:Schools/Search:results_list.html.twig at line 33.

`name` is a valid column name for the `s` table. This did work but moving to a new machine and installing a new version of MySQL has broken this completely. There are some references to this issue http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1800

But no actual solution other than removing the `s.` which also fails

```
 $builder->addOrderBy("name", "ASC");
```

I am a complete loss of what to do, as this seems to be a fairly major issue within Doctrine2's paginator.

I am using MySQL 5.7.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For given error, explicit select statement should do the job.

```
 $builder = $this->createQueryBuilder("s");
 $builder->select("s")
         ->orderBy("s.name", "ASC");
```

But I would recommend using [KnpPaginatorBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle) if you want to use pagination in many different cases. That component is more flexible.

Comment: Thanks. Refactoring for that bundle worked and was pretty simple too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must downgrade your mySql version to 5.6